# What is an efficient way to make rows by every set of two data elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

**Objective**: to take pairs from data and create a new labeled dataframe with the appropriate rows

```
data = [2618926, -1, 2955664, 2978, 2959058, -1, 3038766, 4470, 3044420, -1]

column = ['Date','Value']
```

I need to create a dataframe from the variable 'Data' and display in the following format:

```
Date        Value
2618926     -1
2955664     2978
2959058     -1
2028766     4470
3044420     -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll use my favourite `zip` and `iter` recipe:

```
it = iter(data)
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(it, it)), columns=column)
# Or, let pandas exhaust the iterator for you.
# pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip(it, it), columns=column)

      Date  Value
0  2618926     -1
1  2955664   2978
2  2959058     -1
3  3038766   4470
4  3044420     -1
```

`zip(it, it)` zips together every alternate element together.

---

Another option is using `np.reshape`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(data, (-1, 2)), columns=column)

      Date  Value
0  2618926     -1
1  2955664   2978
2  2959058     -1
3  3038766   4470
4  3044420     -1
```

Comment: I was thinking `pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]), columns=column)` but this is cool.

Comment: @pault That is likely to be a bit faster, but this is so much cleaner and more memory  efficient. I love it.

Answer (score 3):

Feed your df with a dictionary:

```
df= pd.DataFrame( {"Date":data[::2], "Value":data[1::2]} )
```

of list sliced for every 2nd element starting at 0 and 1 index.

Output:

```
      Date  Value
0  2618926     -1
1  2955664   2978
2  2959058     -1
3  3038766   4470
4  3044420     -1
```